# ExpandableListView обработка долгих нажатий

Tags: expandablelistview, android, java

Как у `ExpandableListView` обработать долгие нажатия на group-элементы или на child-элементы ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expandableListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
            //лонгклик был на child'е
            int groupPosition = expandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
            int childPosition = expandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);

            return true;
        } else {
            //лонгклик был на группе
            int groupPosition = expandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

И вроде бы еще нужно в адаптере раздать итемам ID